# Running Xubuntu, the network icon is missing and can't get it back

Tags: network-manager, icons

For the life of me I can't get that network icon back. I have restarted the X server, ran "nm-applet" and restarted NetworkManager. Any ideas? I can provide output for commands if needed.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 06/20/2023:**  Upon further research, missing icons can be caused by the `ayatana-indicator-application`.  A simple removal of the application then a logout and back in, or a reboot could solve the issues:

```
sudo apt remove ayatana-indicator-application
```

---

*You can also check that the Known Items application icon isn't selected for hidden.*

Right click on the panel and select *Panel -> Panel Preferences*

Then choose the *Items* tab and go down and double click on the *Status Notifier Plugin*

[image]

Then in the *Status Notifier Items* for the *Known Items* block, scroll down and make sure that the *Network Manager Applet* hidden check box is not selected.  If it is, unselect it.

[image]

I recommend a reboot after unselecting it.

Comment: Hey Terrance, thanks for answering quickly. The "Network Icon Hidden" box wasn't checked, but then I checked it and unchecked it and the icon came back. So I am not complaining. Thanks!

Comment: @CadenEllis Very cool!  Glad you got it back working!  =)

Comment: It would be only fair to accept that answer. Seems that Terrance found a solution.

Comment: I have the same problem but the list is empty

Comment: @jcubic Maybe try removing the `ayatana-indicator-application`.  `sudo apt remove ayatana-indicator-application` then log out and back in or reboot.

Comment: I was able to resolve it with a reboot, but I only have NetworkManager now. Luckily I only need that icon.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after a couple of days of searching with one note - in Ubuntu 22.04/xfce the item is called "Status Tray Plugin".